# Excel formula inserted with vba returning wrong result

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I developed a macro that loads some codes that I need to lookup and their associated int values into an array. After this, the macro will loop through the lookup array and convert all codes that compose a formula in one column (for now they are not stored as a formula but as a text in "Fórmula Calculo" column, e.g. `dAGR99001/dAGR99002` with no = sign) into their associated int values using the `Range.Replace` method. Later the macro will load the formulas, which already have the codes with their associated int values, as text into an array and loop through the array to prepend an = sign to convert them into proper formulas and print the result in the desired columns.

[image]
Note that the results we can see here (2016) are returning the correct value (`#DIV/0!`) because the associated values for the codes in this year are 0's. The problem only occurs in 2019 for this formula.

The macro is working fine but some of the formulas are returning the wrong result in some situations.
e.g. in the above formula (`dAGR99001/dAGR99002`) both codes are associated with the following values for each month of 2019:

[image]

But instead of returning `=2/2`, for Jan/19, and the result of 1, it's returning `=43498` and similar values for the following months of the year. It's weird because for the previous years the results are the expected.
I noticed that this error is only occurring when the formulas (divisions, sums, subtractions, etc.) deal with values below 10.

I did some research but haven't found any solution, did find some similar problems but not quite the same thing. I tried to change the values for a number format but that didn't work.

This is the vba code that I'm using:

```
Sub Looper()

Dim x As Integer

    For x = 10 To 60
        getformulas x
    Next x

End Sub
```

```
Sub getformulas(MonthNum As Integer)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsLookup As Worksheet
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsPaste As Worksheet
    Dim aLookup() As Variant
    Dim aData() As Variant
    Dim lCodesLookupCol As Long
    Dim lCodesConvertCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lrow As Long

Call OptimizeCode_Begin

    With Sheets("Variaveis")
        lrow = .Range("A:BA").Find(What:="", after:=.Range("A2"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    End With

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Worksheets("Indicadores")
    Set wsLookup = wb.Worksheets("Variaveis")
    Set wsPaste = wb.Worksheets("Formulas")

    aLookup = wsLookup.Range("A2:BA" & lrow) '("A2:AO441")

    lCodesLookupCol = LBound(aLookup, 2)
    lCodesConvertCol = UBound(aLookup, 2)  

    With wsData.Range("H2", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))

            For i = 1 To UBound(aLookup, 1)
                '.Replace aLookup(i, lCodesLookupCol), aLookup(i, lCodesConvertCol), xlPart, , False
                .Replace aLookup(i, lCodesLookupCol), aLookup(i, MonthNum - 4), xlPart, , False
            Next i

            If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
                ReDim aData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
                aData(1, 1) = .Formula
            Else
                aData = .Formula
            End If

            For i = 1 To UBound(aData, 1)
                If Len(aData(i, 1)) > 0 And Left(aData(i, 1), 1) <> "=" Then aData(i, 1) = "=" & aData(i, 1)
                wsData.Cells(i + 1, MonthNum) = aData(i, 1)
                If Left(aData(i, 1), 1) <> "=" Then
                    wsData.Cells(i + 1, MonthNum).Value = "Error"
                End If
                On Error Resume Next
            Next i

        End If

Call OptimizeCode_End
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

    End With

    Worksheets("Formulas").Range("B2:B228").Copy
    Worksheets("Indicadores").Range("H2:H228").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    Application.Goto Worksheets("Indicadores").Cells(2, 6)

End Sub
```

Comment: It's translating `2/2` as `2-Feb` of this year, which has the numeric value 43498 (days since 1/1/1900)

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` makes debugging a nightmare. Unless used in a disciplined way (explicit checking of error codes and then reenabling of error-checking when done with it) it functions as `On Error Hide Bug`. What happens when you delete that line?

Comment: @Rory I noticed that the number was the equivalent of a date but wasn't thinking about it in that way, I mean 2/2 as 2 of February. Any idea how can I avoid this? I'm assuming this must be code related because if I manually type ```=2/2``` it returns 1-

Comment: The `Replace` operation could do it if you had data in there already without an `=` in front of it.

Comment: @JohnColeman some of the rows have no formula defined (on the column "Fórmula Calculo") and when the macro reaches that row it will return the "400" error so I just used that to avoid it. These blank formulas will be defined later.

Comment: @JohnnyAbreu The problem is that you are making an assumption that you know the only possible error that your code can throw and furthermore know that you can safely ignore it. When those assumptions are not true, you could be hiding a bug which, because you are suppressing normal error handling, can be difficult to track down. Step zero in debugging is to remove that line. Even if this particular use-case is okay, if you use that with any regularity sooner or later it will cause you grief.